Copies of $S_6$ in $S_{13}$ (up to conjugacy)
I was trying my hand at this question when my answer contradicted OEIS. According to A378177, there are $9$ copies of $S_6$ within $S_{13}$ up to conjugacy. However, I believe I found $13$.
Any copy of $S_n$ within $S_N$ makes $[N]:=\{1,\cdots,N\}$ into an $S_n$-set. By orbit-stabilizer,
$$ [N] \cong \frac{S_n}{H_1}\sqcup\cdots\sqcup\frac{S_n}{H_k} \tag{$\circ$} $$
as $S_n$-sets. These $S_n$-sets thus correspond to multisets $\{[H_1],\cdots,[H_k]\}$ of (conjugacy classes) of subgroups of $S_n$, whose indices in $S_n$ (counted with multiplicity) sum to $N$.
For the action $S_n\to S_N$ to be an embedding, the action must be faithful. The kernel is the intersection of the normal cores of the stabilizers $H_i$, but the only normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $1,S_n,A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$ and $V_4\triangleleft S_4$, so the multiset just needs one stabilizer other than these.
So I begin applying this to $S_6$, finding small-index subgroups. Recall $S_6$ has an exotic copy of $S_5$ and $A_5$ in it (due to an outer automorphism), call them $S_5^*$ and $A_5^*$. Let $m[H]$ mean $[H],\cdots,[H]$ (listed $m$ times). Then the copies of $S_6$ in $S_{13}$ I found correspond to these multisets:


$\{[S_5],7[S_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],5[S_6],[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],3[S_6],2[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],[S_6],3[A_6]\}$



$\{[S_5^*],7[S_6]\}$
$\{[S_5^*],5[S_6],[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5^*],3[S_6],2[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5^*],[S_6],3[A_6]\}$



$\{2[S_5],[S_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],[S_5^*],[S_6]\}$
$\{2[S_5^*],[S_6]\}$
$\{[A_5],[S_6]\}$
$\{[A_5^*],[S_6]\}$


(I grouped them in a way that makes sense to me.) However, OEIS suggests its numbers came from GAP in the last month or so, so presumably I'm wrong. That means some of my examples above must be conjugate, but that would contradict one of my assumptions:

The conjugacy class of $S_n$ in $S_N$ is determined by $[N]$ as an $S_n$-set
$[N]$ as an $S_n$-set is determined by the multiplicities of the $[H]$s in $(\circ)$

But $(1)$ is true: any bijection $\sigma:[N]\to[N]$ intertwining two actions of $S_n$ means the two embeddings $S_n\to S_N$ are conjugate via $\sigma$ (and vice-versa). And $(2)$ is a standard fact about group actions and classifying $G$-sets. So what's wrong here?

$A^{}_{5}$ and $S^{}{5}$ are isomorphic to $A{5}$ and $S_{5}$, so why should they add new conjugacy classes?

@VivaanDaga Because the left coset spaces $S_6/A_5^$ and $S_6/S_5^\ast$ are not isomorphic to $S_6/A_5$ and $S_6/S_5$ as $S_6$-sets, since $A_5^$ and $S_5^*$ are not conjugate to $A_5$ and $S_5$ (respectively).

There are two issues:

You are counting embeddings $S_6 \to S_{13}$ (or actions of $S_6$ on $\{1,\ldots, 13\}$), while the OEIS sequence is counting subgroups $S_6 \subset S_{13}$. This causes you to overcount certain subgroups.
You've missed a low-index subgroup! $S_3 \times S_3$ (order 36) sits inside $S_6$ in the obvious way. Throw in an element swapping the two factors by conjugation, and you have an order 72 (index 10) subgroup of $S_6$. Let's call this subgroup $H \subset S_6$.

The first issue is solved by noting that two embeddings have the same image iff they differ by pre-composition by an automorphism. Of course, $Out(S_6) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, so we need to modify your list by pairing off elements which differ by putting stars on everything (ie composing each stabilizer with the unique outer automorphism). So for instance, the actions $\{2[S_5],[S_6]\}$ and $\{2[S_5^*],[S_6]\}$ represent the same subgroup of $S_{13}$.
Doing this for you list identifies the first batch with the second batch, $\{2[S_5],[S_6]\}$ with $\{2[S_5^*],[S_6]\}$, and $\{[A_5],[S_6]\}$ with $\{[A_5^*],[S_6]\}$.
Finally, there is the additional subgroup $H\subset S_6$ of index 10 (and, I suppose, his exotic pair $H^*$). Then we must add $\{[H],[A_6],[S_6]\}$ and $\{[H],3[S_6]\}$. This brings the total up to 9:


$\{[S_5],7[S_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],5[S_6],[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],3[S_6],2[A_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],[S_6],3[A_6]\}$



$\{2[S_5],[S_6]\}$
$\{[S_5],[S_5^*],[S_6]\}$
$\{[A_5],[S_6]\}$



$\{[H],[A_6],[S_6]\}$
$\{[H],3[S_6]\}$


I have made no effort to verify that this is an exhaustive list, but the OEIS entry/presumed GAP computation is good enough for me.
(Also this was a great question!)

Ah, of course. I accounted for the outer auto for stabilizers, and accounted for conjugating embeddings in $S_N$, but not precomposing with outer autos. (Also, I haven't checked but it might be interesting to see if $H^*=H$ for any representative outer auto or not.)
